# Принять участие в разработке wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, opensource

Довольно плотно занимаюсь разработкой сайтов на WordPress. CMS мне нравится, но сказать что в ней нет недостатков я не могу. Поскольку это opensource проект, то  мне хотелось бы помочь исправить те недостатки которые я вижу. Собственно вопрос - что для этого нужно сделать? На каком сайте нужно писать исправленные фрагменты кода, и вообще интересно как происходит весь этот процесс.

Comment: http://make.wordpress.org/ :

> This site is the future home for official resources to help people develop for WordPress.

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress только у них уровень намного выше вашего, вряд-ли ваш код пойдет куда-нибудь. А так
 - [вот этот человек несколько минут назад сделал кучку коммитов в WP](https://github.com/markjaquith) спросите у него чем вы можете быть полезны.

Comment: Стоит еще обратить внимание на такую запись на гитхабе:

> WordPress, Git-ified. Synced via SVN every 15 minutes, including branches and 
> tags! This repository is just a mirror of the WordPress subversion repository. 
> Please do not send pull requests. Submit patches to http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ instead.

Т.е., заходите на http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ и читайте раздел Contributing.  
Но если не получится - всегда можно попробовать что-то проще :)

Comment: интересно, почему они всё ещё на svn сидят ?

Comment: Возможно, не ломают то, что работает. Люди, инструменты, привычки, процесс. Мне так кажется

Comment: @eicto диагноз по аватаре?

Comment: Давно это было, насколько я помню по активности оп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ на основании комментариев к вопросу:

[здесь](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) следует создавать новые (и искать существующие) сообщения об ошибках.

инструкция о том, как можно помочь проекту, находится [здесь](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/).